# MongoDB restarted after query on session and collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, openshift

After few seconds of use, my application shutdown for 503 error.
I think the problem is probably due to mongodb, here is the log :

> Tue Sep  1 14:00:50.053 [conn2] update staging.sessions query: { sid: "xxx" }
>   update: { $set: { sid: "xxx", session: { cookie: { path: "/", _expires: false, originalMaxAge: false, httpOnly: true, expires: false, maxAge: false, data: { originalMaxAge: false, expires: false, httpOnly: true, path: "/" } }, passport: { user: "xxx" }, csrfSecret: "xxx" }, createdAt: new Date(1441130449809) } } nscanned:3 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:1 locks(micros) w:239212 239ms
>
> Tue Sep 1 14:02:01.394 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 10ms
>
> note: noprealloc may hurt performance in many applications
>
> Tue Sep 1 14:02:10.519 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=412562 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/openshift/xxx/mongodb/data/ 64-bit host=ex-std-xxx.prod.rhcloud.com

I use express 4 with this configuration :

```
app.use(session({
    store: require('mongoose-session')(mongoose),
    secret: 'xxx',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
```

Is this a problem with sessions ?
Do I need to change noprealloc to false on mongodb config ?

Comment: Are you calling mongoose.connect somewhere?

Comment: Yes just before mongoose.connect(URL)

Comment: And it connects successfully? Do you have a callback attached to the connect() call to see if it was successful?

Comment: Yes, the application is running correctly, there is a lot of sub-documents in the row I used to test, but after many interaction like update, delete requests, 503 happen on response.